# How do you join Telephony.Sms to ContactsContract.Contacts?

Tags: java, android

I do not want to look up the number first, I want to start with the contact and then take information in that set and query the Telephony.sms data. However, there isn't a lookup_key in the Telephony.sms data from what I can tell.

Comment: You need to make this question more descriptive.